# OpenGL render order causing triangles in the foreground to be drawn in the background

Tags: cocoa, opengl, render

I am drawing my triangles in a world the triangles in the background but when I go behind it the triangle isn't in the foreground (like it should be).

I put a video on YouTube showing the problem [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4UPJ9HxRTFY) (make sure you read the description)

EDIT:

```
//create instance of camera class
mainCamera = [[Camera alloc]init];
//Tell window to log mouse events
[[self window] setAcceptsMouseMovedEvents:YES];
//Timer for updating frames
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1/30 target:self selector:@selector(redraw) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
//keep timer running during event tracking
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSEventTrackingRunLoopMode];
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSModalPanelRunLoopMode];

glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glClearDepth(1.0f);
glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);    
glEnable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH);


glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
//self in this case is my view. The code below is getting the size of the view.
gluPerspective(45.0f, [self frame].size.width / [self frame].size.height, 1.0f, 1000.0f);   

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
//creating triangle objects
```

Comment: I think the purple triangle is in the foreground, but you have it somewhat transparent, if you change that it may be easier to tell.

Comment: @JamesBlack: No i found out that the other triangle are being drawn over it. depth testing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you create your context with a depth buffer?

Did you activate depth testing with `glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);`?

Are you using an appropriate `glDepthFunc` depth test?

Comment: I activated the `GL_DEPTH_TEST`, Not sure about the other 2 (Kinda new to OpenGL)

Comment: Looking at my code it looks like i do have a Depth buffer (assuming the command is `glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);`)

Comment: I realized that there wasn't a DepthFunc so I added it with LEQUAL and still no change.

Comment: @ChaseWalden: How do you _create_ your OpenGL context? You know, your OpenGL window?

Comment: I use Apple's cocoa framework to make the window. My setup is Enabling Depthtesting, model smoothing and line smoothing. i then do `glClearDepth(1.0);` I set the Clear color. Switch matrix mode to projection, set the perspective, load the Identity and then switch the matrix mode to model view. Hope that makes sense. Apple has a prebuilt view that tells opengl where to draw to but i have to do the setup.

Comment: I tried adding my code to my original question but  don't have enough rep. srry

Comment: @ChaseWalden: Editing your own question is something you can always do. SO probably thinks you're trying to dump too much code in. So cut down the amount of code you're trying to post. At least post whatever Cocoa initialization code you have. There must be some way of telling Cocoa what kind of framebuffer you want.

Comment: @ChaseWalden: You must have some way of affecting your OpenGL framebuffer? Whether you want multisampling, sRGB framebuffers, AUX buffers, that kind of thing?

Comment: I just found the answer. There is a checkbox in Interface Builder that allows depth testing in the view (even though I enabled it in the setup function). Thank you for all your help.